# Why are terminal commands 'git add .', git commit...' and 'git push...' listed as optional when deploying React project?

Tags: reactjs, git, github-pages

Apologies, I am still a bit confused by git, although I am trying to teach myself more and improve.

I recently successfully deployed a React website to GitHub pages, following the often recommended steps of installing gh-pages to the project, adding a homepage property to the package.json file, adding scripts to the scripts properties on the package.json file, running 'npm run deploy' and so on. It worked fine, and now a build of the project has been added to my repository ([here](https://github.com/StephenDoyle10/stephendoyle10.github.io)), and I can view the actual project online ([here](https://stephendoyle10.github.io/#/)).

However, the issue I have is this: most guides on deploying a react app also mention the following steps:
in the terminal type:

git add .

git commit -m "commit"

git push origin master

These final steps are often listed as optional. Everything worked fine without me doing these steps: my code was added to the repository, and my website is deployed online, so **what do these steps do exactly? Why are they considered optional? What is best practice?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These commands are not optional to me - when using only the command-line Git client, these commands accomplish the interaction of pushing the code (that, after you edit it, only exists locally on your own PC) to the Git repository server.

> Everything worked fine without me doing these steps: my code was added to the repository, and my website is deployed online

I can see the following possibilities:

- You are using another Git client and the push was done there;
- You are using a Git tool (e.g. editing purely on the GitHub website), where the push happened without you being aware of it;
- You did the terminal commands, without being aware of them;

A common resource to learn more about Git would be the Git book on the official Git SCM website: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2